# how to get angle of the complex argument with period?

Tags: python, numpy, angle, complex-numbers

## Example 1

for example, I have a serials of vector

```
vectors = [
    [1+1j], [1j], [-1+1j], [-1], [-1-1j], [-1j], [1-1j], [1], 
    [1+1j], [1j], [-1+1j], [-1], [-1-1j], [-1j], [1-1j], [1], 
]
```

you may find that the 16 elements in `vectors` actually rotate around the origin of coordinates counter-clockwise by 45 degrees(or pi/4 radians) each other. So what I actually need is

```
  pi/4,  2*pi/4,  3*pi/4,  4*pi/4,  5*pi/4,  6*pi/4,  7*pi/4,  8*pi/4, 
9*pi/4, 10*pi/4, 11*pi/4, 12*pi/4, 13*pi/4, 14*pi/4, 15*pi/4, 16*pi/4
```

But `np.angle(vectors)` gets

```
pi/4, 2*pi/4, 3*pi/4, 4*pi/4, -3*pi/4, -2*pi/4, -pi/4, 0,
pi/4, 2*pi/4, 3*pi/4, 4*pi/4, -3*pi/4, -2*pi/4, -pi/4, 0
```

## Example 2

for example, I have a serials of vector as

```
vectors = [
    [1], [1-j], [-1j], [-1-1j], [-1], [-1+1j], [1j], [1+1j], 
    [1], [1-j], [-1j], [-1-1j], [-1], [-1+1j], [1j], [1+1j], 
]
```

you may find that the 16 elements in `vectors` actually rotate around the origin of coordinates clockwise by 45 degrees(or pi/4 radians) each other. So what I actually need is

```
 0*pi/4, -1*pi/4,  -2*pi/4,  -3*pi/4,  -4*pi/4,  -5*pi/4,  -6*pi/4,  -7*pi/4, 
-8*pi/4, -9*pi/4, -10*pi/4, -11*pi/4, -12*pi/4, -13*pi/4, -14*pi/4, -15*pi/4
```

## Example 3

for

```
vectors = [
    [1-1j], [-1j], [-1-1j], [-1], [-1+1j], [1j], [1+1j], [1], 
    [1-1j], [-1j], [-1-1j], [-1], [-1+1j], [1j], [1+1j], [1], 
]
```

I need the answer to be

```
 -*pi/4,  -2*pi/4,  -3*pi/4,  -4*pi/4,  -5*pi/4,  -6*pi/4,  -7*pi/4,  -8*pi/4, 
-9*pi/4, -10*pi/4, -11*pi/4, -12*pi/4, -13*pi/4, -14*pi/4, -15*pi/4, -15*pi/4
```

## General statement, or what I need

so how to make a new `angle_with_period` function, which meets the following conditions

1. the input parameter is an list/array `[v1, v2, v3...]`, and abs(angle between v[i] and v[i+1]) is always not bigger than pi
2. `angle_with_period` calculates the angle of every elements from the positive real axis on the complex plane
3. for v1, angle_with_period acts like np.angle, that is

```
    in  |   0   |  1+1j  |   -1   | -1-1j  | 1-1j  |
    ----+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
    out |   0   |  pi/4  | 4*pi/4 |-3*pi/4 | -pi/4 |
```

3. if `vecAnswer = angle_with_period([v1, v2, v3...])`, then vecAnswer is a monotone increased or decreased array

thanks

Comment: What about vectors = [[1j], [1+1j], [1], [1-1j], [-1j], [-1-1j], [-1], [-1+1j], 
                                    [1j], [1+1j], [1], [1-1j], [-1j], [-1-1j], [-1], [-1+1j]]. What are the angles for this?

Comment: 2*pi/4, pi/4, 0, -pi/4, ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `diff`, `mod`, `cumsum`:

```
def mono_angle(x):
    a = np.angle(x)
    b = np.trim_zeros(a, 'f')
    if b.size==0: return a
    b[1:] = np.diff(b) % (np.sign(b[0])*2*np.pi)
    a[-b.size:] = b.cumsum()
    return a
```

For example:

```
>>> vectors = [
...     [1], [1-1j], [-1j], [-1-1j], [-1], [-1+1j], [1j], [1+1j], 
...     [1], [1-1j], [-1j], [-1-1j], [-1], [-1+1j], [1j], [1+1j], 
... ]
>>> mono_angle(np.ravel(vectors))
array([  0.        ,  -0.78539816,  -1.57079633,  -2.35619449,
        -3.14159265,  -3.92699082,  -4.71238898,  -5.49778714,
        -6.28318531,  -7.06858347,  -7.85398163,  -8.6393798 ,
        -9.42477796, -10.21017612, -10.99557429, -11.78097245])
```

Note: you may also want to look at `np.unwrap` which is similar. It works on your examples but does not in general match your description.